# What sensor can penetrate the glass window and detect any moving object in front of the car?

Tags: sensor, distance

I want to put this sensor on top of the dashboard in my car. The signal can penetrate the front window. The sensor can also sense any moving object in front of my car. It should also be able to get the distance from my car to the car in the front. Any available sensor I can choose to use?

thanks!

Comment: Light? There are IR proximity sensors. Through you may as well have a sensor on your grill.

Comment: Is the car moving? If so then the entire WORLD is moving relative to the car and the sensor.

Comment: You realize that "it should be able to get the distance from my car to the car in the front" (besides being wrongly formulated) implies being able to recognize a car vs another object. It rules out anything else but cameras, probably even requires two for estimating distance accurately, and *heavy* image processing? It isn't a sensor, it is a whole system and I think many engineers from car manufacturers are currently scratching their heads on it.

Comment: Any sensor propelled with sufficient velocity should be able to penetrate the front windshield of your car, unless it is some type of ballistic or bullet resistant glass. The challenge will be to find a sensor which remains functional after being accelerated to the necessary velocity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest either camera or radar or similar microwave sensor ....http://www.limpkin.fr/public/HB100/HB100_Microwave_Sensor_Application_Note.pdf
IR (lidar or swept beam) may have problems with laminated glass.